# How can I let my template class deduce the return and argument type of a function pointer template argument

Tags: c++, winapi, templates

I'm using a little helper template to wrap different Windows functions for releasing resources, such as:

```
template <typename Resource, typename ReturnType, ReturnType (WINAPI *GlobalFn)( Resource )>
struct GlobalWINAPIFn {
    inline void release( Resource r ) { (void)GlobalFn( r ); }
};
```

Instantiations of this template are actually passed as an argument to another template (which expects the given type to expose a `release` function which takes the type `Resource`). This helper is used to easily wrap global methods.

I'm using it like

```
// wraps BOOL WINAPI CloseHandle( HANDLE );
typedef GlobalWINAPIFn<HANDLE, BOOL, ::CloseHandle> HANDLEDestructor;

// wraps LONG WINAPI RegCloseKey( HKEY );
typedef GlobalWINAPIFn<HKEY, LONG, ::RegCloseKey> HKEYDestructor;
```

It works, but I wonder - is there any way to rewrite the template so that I can just write

```
typedef GlobalWINAPIFn<::CloseHandle> HANDLEDestructor;
typedef GlobalWINAPIFn<::RegCloseKey> HKEYDestructor;
```

And the return types are deduces automatically? Some sort of type factory function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a look at `boost::function_traits` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/libs/functional/function_traits.html

Comment: +1 for pointing this out. Doesn't answer my question directly, but maybe I can use this to implement an answer myself. It's promising to see that the return type and the argument type can be extracted from a function pointer.